# make DD-WRT send its public IP to an email address

Tags: dd-wrt, dynamic-dns

Is it possible to setup DD-WRT (router firmware family) to send out its IP somewhere? Periodically, or preferably, whenever it just changed?

I am not ready to set up (and pay for) dynamic DNS yet, but I need the IP for incoming traffic.

Comment: I have a python code that I use as a mailer (using Google's SMTP servers) and another than checks the IP via crown and emails using the mailer to if changed. Can you install python on DD-WRT (I've not tried, but the scripts work well and I can link them for you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an out of the box method to [configure the DDNS options in a DD-WRT router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DDNS_-_How_to_setup_Custom_DDNS_settings_using_embedded_inadyn_-_HOWTO), for free. If that isn't enough you could configure [multiple DDNS solutions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DDNS_-_How_to_manage_multiple_DDNS_accounts_using_embedded_inadyn_-_HOWTO).

If any of these options works you've [another alternative for the router](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/DDNS_-_Alternate_way_to_manage_multiple_DDNS_accounts_using_updatedd_-_HOWTO).

If nothing works then you could configure [any of the DDNS Software available for free](http://dnslookup.me/dynamic-dns/) in one of the computers behind your router.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the in-router solution, but as long as you have a computer running behind it, setting up an ip change notifier application is easy.  That would monitor its public IP and email you when it changes.

Here's one of many:
http://ipchangeinformer.codeplex.com/